# What's the best way to make a search box with auto-suggest appearing on top of other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, search-box

I've made a search box with auto-suggestions. I don't want to have the suggestions push down the other elements on the page.

What I did to fix this:

I gave the suggestions `position: fixed` and added a window event listener to update its `top` and `left` on scroll, to make it appear as if it's dropping down from the search box.

This is quite obviously not a good way to achieve this at all. Can anyone give pointers on how to improve this, please? Thanks!

Comment: you should make a working example with html/css/js. As the question is now it could be any given solution.

Comment: Provide code samples

Comment: "best way" is subjective

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your suggestions are coming from (AJAX call? fixed list on page? something entirely different?) so it's not possible to provide a full example.  However, you're going to be much better off using an existing widget rather than building your own.

If you have a fixed list of suggestions, consider using a `<datalist>` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

If you are using ajax to retrieve suggestions, consider using jQuery UI's autocomplete or a similar solution: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Basically it sounds like you are reinventing capabilities that already exist and are already implemented in a user friendly and multi-browser-compatible way.  If you have a strong reason to do so, at least provide code samples of your solution so that people can assist!

Comment: The problem with datalist is that you can't style it.